# API Name for Developement mode

Tags: apex, visualforce

What is the API name for "Developement Mode".
Is it "UserPreferencesApexPagesDeveloperMode"?

I am trying to retrive the list of User with enabled Developement Mode.
Here is my query `select id,Name,UserName where UserPreferencesApexPagesDeveloperMode='True';`
This says error. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, API name for "Development Mode" is **UserPreferencesApexPagesDeveloperMode**.

```
select id,Name,UserName from user where UserPreferencesApexPagesDeveloperMode=true
```

In your where clause you are trying to compare `UserPreferencesApexPagesDeveloperMode` which datatype is boolean to string `'true'`

And you did'nt give FROM clause in the query. I think this(`UserPreferencesApexPagesDeveloperMode`) field lies in object user.
hence FROM clause should be `from user` .

I hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Salesforce documentation says it [here](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_user.htm) and your query is fine for this requirement.

> **UserPreferencesApexPagesDeveloperMode** - When true, indicates the user has enabled developer mode for editing
>   Visualforce pages and controllers.